# Laravel find by primary key and return a single column value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do a search and return a single value. I am getting different results depending on how I try to get the value.

If the table has the following values:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Professional I |
| 2 | Professional II |
| 3 | Professional III |
| 4 | Professional IV |
| 5 | Teacher I |
| 6 | Teacher II |

And I set `$type = 4`, I expect to get `Professional IV`.
`CertificateRequest::find($type)->name;`
Returns `Professional VI` which is what I want.

However,

`CertificateRequest::find($type)->value("name"));`

and

`CertificateRequest::find($type)->first()->value("name");`
Both return `Professional I`

What am I doing wrong? The problem with the first approach is if `$type = null`, I get `Attempt to read property "name" on null`. It also becomes harder to dynamically pass a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
CertificateRequest::where('id', $type)->value("name"));
```

The difference is that `find` executes the query, which means that `value` seems to execute a second query without the type parameter. The `where` method modifies the query without executing it, allowing the `value` method to execute the query and return a result.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```php
CertificateRequest::findOrFail($type)->name;
```

Will return data or 404, not null.

Comment: Thanks but how do I `value` so that I can dynamically set the field that I need? The Laravel documentation describes using `value` to get column values.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I want to be able to do something like `CertificateRequest::find($type)->value($field));`

Comment: What I am suggesting you is using `YourModel::findOrFail($id)` as a better method for your query because that will return  a Model object, you are accesing the property with `->name` part

Comment: `$myModel=MyModel::findOrFail($id)`; and then you can `$myModel->name` or `$myModel->id`

Comment: Well the table has additional columns so it would be more than just name or id

Comment: Inside $myModel you have all the properties of the Model. use `dd(SmyModel)` to see them

Comment: I know what columns I have. I wanted to be able to dynamically pull a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`$data = CertificateRequest::where('id',$type)->get();`

**EDIT**

```
CertificateRequest::select($field)->where('id',$type);
```

Maybe this can help !

Comment: This gets the entire object, not just the single value the question wants.

Comment: Yes this gets the entire object. Just need the value.